# Switch off heading if there are no related products inside an if_array inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, foreach

I want to display a heading title 'Related Products' if there are matches in an array and hide the title if there are not. My code below shows the title regardless. How do i switch it off if there are no products?

As you can see I have commented out the original code whereby I tried to do the checking inside the query but that did not work, otherwise I could have just places teh heading below the `if ($related_products->have_posts()){` line.

```
            <?php 

                // Query products where product title matches a tag in the current article

                $current_article_tags = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'knowledge_hub_tag', array('fields' => 'names'));

                echo '<pre>'; print_r($current_article_tags); echo '</pre>';

                $related_products = new WP_Query(array(
                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
                  'post_type'=> 'product',
                  /*'post_title' => array(
                      array(
                          //'taxonomy' => $current_article_tags,
                          'post_title' => 'varilite icon mid',
                          'operator'=> 'IN' //Or 'AND' or 'NOT IN'
                      ),
                  )*/
                ));

                //echo '<pre>'; print_r($related_products); echo '</pre>';

                $products = $related_products->posts;

                //echo '<pre>'; print_r($products); echo '</pre>';

                if ($related_products->have_posts()){

                    echo '<h4>Related products</h4>';

                    foreach($products as $product) {
                        if(in_array($product->post_title, $current_article_tags, true)) {
                            echo '<p><a href="'.get_permalink( $product ).'">'.get_the_title($product).'</a></p>';
                        }
                    }

                }

                        
     

                //wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
```

Comment: You have to call `have_posts` on the appropriate object - that is a method of WP_Query, so you need to call it on `$related_products`.

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it to work, check out my code where I have commented it out. For some reason that didn't work :(

Comment: _“I only want to display the title if any of the product post titles match any of the current article tags”_ - ah, so then this is not about whether the query _had_ any posts. You are not filtering for any such kind of condition in your database query - so that will _have_ posts either way. You will either have to add this as a selection criterion to your query in the first place; or you have to loop over all the posts in the result first, to be able to determine that _none_ of them satisfied your condition.

Comment: I tried looping which worked for the products but repeated the title 'related products' when i only want to display that once and only if there is a match in the array.

Comment: Sounds like you output the title _inside_ the loop, instead of after …

Comment: If you don’t want to loop twice - then don‘t `echo` your posts inside the loop, but append them to a string variable. If that string is _not_ empty after the loop, then output your title, followed by the string contents.

Comment: I tried outputting the title inside loop but it repeated, after isn't useful visually.

Comment: I did not say that you should output it after you output the titles already, I said that you should output it after a loop that checks if your condition is fulfilled for any of the posts. (And if you don’t want to loop _twice_, to first check your condition against all posts, then do as I said in the previous comment.)

Comment: ah ok, i'll give it a go, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php 

// Query products where product title matches a tag in the current article

$current_article_tags = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'knowledge_hub_tag', array('fields' => 'names'));

echo '<pre>'; print_r($current_article_tags); echo '</pre>';

$related_products = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type'=> 'product',
  /*'post_title' => array(
      array(
          //'taxonomy' => $current_article_tags,
          'post_title' => 'varilite icon mid',
          'operator'=> 'IN' //Or 'AND' or 'NOT IN'
      ),
  )*/
));

//echo '<pre>'; print_r($related_products); echo '</pre>';

$products = $related_products->posts;

$show_title = false;

foreach($products as $product) {
    if(in_array($product->post_title, $current_article_tags, true)) {
        $show_title = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($show_title){

    echo '<h4>Related products</h4>';

    foreach($products as $product) {
        if(in_array($product->post_title, $current_article_tags, true)) {
            echo '<p><a href="'.get_permalink( $product ).'">'.get_the_title($product).'</a></p>';
        }
    }

}
//wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Just check if the array has any item. If it does then only show the title and the products.

Comment: This still displays the title regardless, I may have not bee clear in my post, I only want to display the title if any of the product post titles match any of the current article tags.

Comment: Basically, the related posts would be all the products having the same tag as current product ?

Comment: Nearly, it will be all the products who's title match that of the current article tags. So I would add product title as tags in an article to link them to the product - which works, but I only want to display the section heading 'related products' if there is a match.

Comment: @Amesey I have updated the answer, this should work, pls give it a go.

Comment: Thank my man, that works perfectly, you're a scholar! :)

Comment: is there a way to query the tag slug instead of name? This way the comparison doesn't have to be case sensitive.